# Scala, how to specify function parameter with multiple traits?

Tags: scala

I have following piece of code, and I think my question will be apparent once you see it.

```
trait hasId {
  def id: String
}

trait hasCount {
  def count: Int
}

case class Foo(id: String, count: Int) extends hasId with hasCount

// This is the function I want to write
def printData(data: hasId and hasCount): Unit = {
  println(data.id + ": " data.count);
}
```

How should I do to declare the function signature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to the answer is `with` keyword, which is used in the meaning of your `and`. Generics as Terry Dactyl wrote are one possible solution:

```
def printData[T <: hasId with hasCount](data: T): Unit = {
  println(data.id + ": " + data.count)
}
```

Another is a `type` alias using `with`:

```
type hasIdAndCount = hasId with hasCount
def printData(data: hasIdAndCount): Unit = {
  println(data.id + ": " + data.count)
}
```

Or even directly:

```
def printData(data: hasId with hasCount): Unit = {
  println(data.id + ": " + data.count)
}
```

Comment: Are there pros and cons for each approach?

Comment: Yes, T <: HasId with HasCount accepts any type that implements HasId with HasCount. The other methods accept only type HasId with HasCount

Comment: @TerryDactyl I disagree. It accepts anything derived from them, as even the original code demonstrates - `Foo` is not `hasId with hasCount`, it only implements them, still all three solutions work with it.

Comment: scala> printData(Foo("a",2))
<console>:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo
 required: hasId with hasCount
       printData(Foo("a",2))

Comment: @TerryDactyl Are you sure? I do not get his error (and I do not see why I should get it). `Foo` is `hasId with hasCount`, as it implements both of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
def hasData[T <: HasId with HasCount](data: T): Unit = ???
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment? Is this proper syntax?

Comment: `T <: Whatever` is a bit like saying "this generic type extends this other stuff". Then if you say "data is type T", you are saying that "data is a type which extends this other stuff"

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-define-method-generic-parameter-must-extend-base-type

Comment: I tried to type this in a scala worksheet. And I couldn't understand it.

Comment: This is correct syntax. <: is called an upper type bound. It means the function will accept instances of `T` that are subtypes of `HasId with HasCount`. This could be `Apple with HasId with HasCount`, `Shark with HasId with Has Count` or any other type that implements `HasId with HasCount`.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow like @TerryDactyl's answer better, but here is another way:

```
// This is the corrected function 
def printData(data: hasId with hasCount): Unit = {
 println(data.id + ": " + data.count)
}
```

---

EDIT:

Since the comments showed that I needed to explain and since the [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Yaneeve/hAu9OdzhQ8esvj5ZP0xU4g) link didn't work, following is the compiled code, with the compilation errors, I hope it helps:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait hasId {
  def id: String
}

trait hasCount {
  def count: Int
}

trait Both extends hasId with hasCount

case class Foo(id: String, count: Int) extends Both
case class Bar(id: String, count: Int) extends hasId with hasCount
case class Baz(id: String, count: Int) extends Both



def printData(data: hasId with hasCount): Unit = {
 println(data.id + ": " + data.count)
}


def printDataT[T <: hasId with hasCount](data: T): Unit = {
 println(data.id + ": " + data.count)
}


val s = Seq(Foo("idFoo", 1), Bar("idBar", 2))

val fooss = Seq(Foo("idFoo", 1), Foo("idFoo2", 2))
val boths = Seq(Foo("idFoo", 1), Baz("idBaz2", 2))


s.foreach(printData)
fooss.foreach(printData)
boths.foreach(printData)

fooss.foreach(printDataT[Foo])
fooss.foreach(printDataT[Both])
boths.foreach(printDataT[Both])
boths.foreach(printDataT[Foo])

s.foreach(printDataT[hasId with hasCount])
s.foreach(printDataT[Both])
s.foreach(printDataT[Foo])




// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:54: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo => Unit
 required: Product with Serializable with hasId with hasCount => ?
              s.foreach(printDataT[Foo])
                                  ^
<console>:48: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo => Unit
 required: Both with Product with Serializable => ?
              boths.foreach(printDataT[Foo])
                                      ^
<console>:51: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Both => Unit
 required: Product with Serializable with hasId with hasCount => ?
              s.foreach(printDataT[Both])
                                  ^
```

Comment: Can you share with me why you think @TerryDactyl answer better?

Comment: You cannot call printData with an instance of Foo... You will get Type mismatch - found : Foo, required hasId with hasCount.

Comment: @Man-KitYau look at the following [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Yaneeve/k78PJ7JxSUyPMy62KRQBZQ])

Comment: To explain why I like the generic way better, when calling `printData` without generics, as listed above will accept any instance that adheres to the contract i.e. is both an `hasId` and a `hasCount`. When you go the generic way then the upper bound is set to `T`. 
See the scastie in the comment

Comment: @Yaneeve I do not see a difference, unless you do something with T - e.g. return `data` back. Can you elaborate? To me it seems the same, it does not matter if you state the requirements as bounds, or as a type. I do not see how is the scastie you have linked related - decode and encode, no hasId / hasCount at all?

Comment: I am trying but I fail to understand what you mean. Your current code shows you cannot use `printDataT[Both]` to process a list of `Foo` - but why would you do that, when `s.foreach(printDataT[hasId with hasCount])` or even `s.foreach(printDataT)` works?

Comment: @Suma `printDataT[Both]` fails on a mixed sequence of `Foo` and `Bar` because `Bar` is not a `Both`,it does not fail on a list of `Foo`s. "Why would you do that?" you ask. Obviously this is a contrived situation. The only point I was trying to make is that the generic formulation that Terry Dactyl introduced would also allow for more specific types to be enforced by the compiler.